# How can a database become observable to a program

Tags: java, asp-classic

From what I have heard about the 'Observer-Observable' pattern, can anybody tell me if there is any way by which there is no need to create an Observable in the programming language, but database (in which the table which we are observing) himself tell the Observable that there is a change in the database, and then that Observable notify to all the Observers. So that there is no program which sense the database every time.

Comment: database triggers coupled with database specific capabilities to call out/notify the observers?

Comment: @Ryan: Could You provide more details? I.e. how could listeners be notified?

Answer (score 1):

Use DB Triggers.

Depending on the DB that will be a stored procedure, very likely you can do a HTTP request from there to a port your application is providing.

But the question is: do you really need an observer on DB level as this is very bad practice, cant you write a service front end and implement the listening/observing on that level?

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilities, for example, from Oracle you can launch Java programs/code from triggers/SPs. There is probably some similar functionality in other DBs as well. But it depends on what you want to do with this change.

Normally, an application should be querying about the current state of the database, and determine how to notify the user on inconsistencies between expected and observed state. It would be too much overhead, in my opinion, to always maintain a current view of the db.

If you want to do something like send out an email for some particular action... maybe a trigger to a program or stored procedure is the way to go. If you want to update some other part of the database, keep that self contained within the db code.

I guess what I'm trying to say is, depending on what your goal is... the **observable pattern** may or may not be the best approach